# What is corel doing on my udp connections for Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, tcpip, udp, process-explorer, sysinternals

I have a weird `mc.corel.com` address lingering in Chrome and some parts of svchost processes, what is going on?

[image: SysInternals PE pic]

Answer (score 1):

I assume you tried to or installed Corel Draw on your PC. That IP address is Corel Draw's server address. Remove it if you are no longer using it.

Comment: Sure, but I have alot of software installed and yet its only corels adress that is attached to my chrome process and svchost processes